# Trying to retrieve data from firebase but data is not displaying

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have two textViews in my layout and I was trying to retrieve data from the firebase database and set that to the textViews (if that make sense) but nothing is displaying when I try to retrieve it. Here is my code and also my Json structure on firebase. Can someone please help me.

Json structure :

```
  "Clicks_and_Views" : {
    "-MHXh3N9b7tXkATD2Zyg" : {
      "clicks" : 1,
      "views" : 6
    }
  },
```

Code

```
final DatabaseReference databaseReference2 = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance("https://poopy0-45091.firebaseio.com").getReference("Clicks_and_Views").child(getid);

databaseReference2.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            for(DataSnapshot ds: snapshot.getChildren()){
              Long one = ds.child("clicks").getValue(Long.class);
              Long two = ds.child("views").getValue(Long.class);

                txt1.setText((int) one.longValue());
                txt2.setText((int) two.longValue());
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `databaseReference2` points all the way down to an individual item in the JSON: `/Clicks_and_Views/$id`. So when you load that, you get a snapshot with the individual properties (`clicks` and `views`) of that single item.

For that reason you don't need to loop over `snapshot.getChildren()` in your `onDataChange` method:

```
final DatabaseReference databaseReference2 = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance("https://poopy0-45091.firebaseio.com").getReference("Clicks_and_Views").child(getid);
databaseReference2.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
        Long one = snapshot.child("clicks").getValue(Long.class);
        Long two = snapshot.child("views").getValue(Long.class);
        ....
    }
```

you only need to loop over the child nodes if there are/may be multiple child nodes in the results, for example: if you'd read all `Clicks_and_Views`, or perform a query against it.